# JavaScript behaving differently on Mac and PC? I know it shouldn't

Tags: javascript, css, windows, macos, browser

I've created a pagination script that takes a long block of text and breaks it into pages. First, the text is loaded into a div with the id `#page`. Then the script measures the height of `#page` and calculates how many pages it should be broken into to fit into the `div` with class `.detailsholder`.

The div .detailsholder is cleared out, and the appropriate number of page divs are added inside. (Each one actually has the entire text of #page inside, but the top margin is set negatively, the height is fixed, and overflow is set to hidden, so only the proper amount appears.)

And it works great, except for this: while Safari and Firefox on the Mac work perfectly, IE and Firefox on Windows add an extra page. Because of the way the pages are created, as described above in parentheses, the last page appears blank -- the text is shifted too far up to appear in the page `window`.

Here's the code. I'm using jQuery, as you can see.

```
var descHeight = $('#page').outerHeight();
if (descHeight > 250 ) {
   var numberOfPages = Math.round(descHeight/210)+1; //Figure out how many pages
   var artistText = $('#page').html();               //Grab the text into a variable
   $('.detailsholder').empty();                      //Empty the container so we can fill
                                                     //it with pages
   for (i=0;i<=numberOfPages-1;i++) {                //Each page has the entire text
                                                     //content, but is shifted up and
      var shiftUp = 0-(210 * i);                     //cut off at the bottom.
      $('.detailsholder').append('<div id="page' + (i+1) + '" class="page" style="height:225px;"><div style="border:dotted 1px red;margin-top:' + shiftUp + 'px"' + artistText + '</div>');
   }
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see one problem in the algorithm. `Math.round` should be `Math.floor` in order to give the correct number of pages. In order to see why assume that `descHeight` is `400`. Then you would need only 2 pages of height `210` each, but `Math.round(400/210) + 1 == 3`. Could it be that a combination of this problem together with a different standard font size between platforms (which will probably affect `descHeight` and trigger the problem) is the reason for the behaviour you observe?

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried it across similar platformed computers with different resolution/font settings?

I think this problem might have more to do with display settings and the CSS part of your Javascript then platform differences. My CSS isn't great, but you may want to avoid px and try to use a % instead.

**The following might help with your diagnostics:**

- http://browsersize.com/
- [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) (for Firefox)
- [Developer Toolbar](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=18359) (for IE)
- [Web Inspector](http://macdevelopertips.com/safari/firebug-like-tools-in-safari.html) (for Safari, haven't personally tried this one)

Answer (score 1):

Add some alerts to see how the calculations are coming out. If you get different results in different browsers then you will have to make adjustments to handle the differences

Answer (score 1):

In the last line of the script, the second opening div tag: it seems it is not closed. Maybe this causes problems?

Comment: Good eyes, I don't know if would cause the issue with HTML being so lax about things like that. Still worth fixing. +1